# I want to call custom directive on button click and passing attributes as a parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

This is html code

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="get(selected_items)">Genrate</button>    

<pre>selected roles = {{selected_items}}</pre>

<grid table-data="data" cols="columnDefs" sortcols="name" pagination="true" enablefiltering="true" />
```

This is my directive

```
 app.directive('grid', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: function ($elem, $attr) {
                if ($attr.pagination == "true") {
                    return '<div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="options" ui-grid-pagination></div>';
                }
                else {
                    return '<div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="options" ></div>';
                }
            },
            scope: {},
            compile: function (cElem, cAttrs) {
                return {
                    pre: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                        scope.options = {};
                        if (iAttrs.pagination == "true") {
                            scope.options = {
                                paginationPageSizes: [6, 10, 20],
                                paginationPageSize: 6
                            };
                        }
                        if (iAttrs.enablefiltering=="true") {
                            scope.options.enableFiltering = true;
                        } 
                        scope.options.columnDefs = scope.$parent.$eval(iAttrs.cols);
                        var array;
                        if (iAttrs.sortcols.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                            array = iAttrs.sortcols.split(',');
                            _.each(scope.options.columnDefs, function (object) {
                                object.enableColumnMenu = false;
                                _.each(array, function (obj) {
                                    if (object.field == obj) {
                                        object.enableSorting = true;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (object.enableSorting = true)
                                            return;
                                        object.enableSorting = false;
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        else {                               
                            _.each(scope.options.columnDefs, function (object) {
                                object.enableColumnMenu = false;
                                if (object.field == iAttrs.sortcols) {
                                    object.enableSorting = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    object.enableSorting = false;
                                }
                            });
                        }                        
                        scope.options.data = iAttrs.tableData;                            
                       scope[iAttrs.tableData] = scope.$parent.$eval(iAttrs.tableData);                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

when i click on button get function should be fired and directive should be called but the attributes `cols`,`pagination`, and 'table-data` should be set when button click how should i implement this?

Comment: Show us your directive.

Comment: @JoeLloyd i added my directive just now

Comment: I think you need a `link` function that monitors for changes in the attributes

Comment: Could you please plunker me?